# Create a model in Model folder in MVC can't be detected by Create view Window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a Model in MVC model folder :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace EducationMVC.Models
{
    public class ScoreStudentPresentation
    {
        public string id { set; get; }
        public string StudentNumber { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Family { set; get; }
        public string Score { set; get; }
        public string ConfirmScore { set; get; }
    }
}
```

So i create a controller to handle this model .When i want to create a list of this model using the Wizard windows(i.e Add view).In dropdownlist i can't find my model's Name **ScoreStudentPresentation**.

I have several models in my Model folder and they work correctly.

My controller code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DomainClasses;
using EducationModel;
using EducationRepositor;


namespace EducationMVC.Controllers
{
    public class ScoreController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Score/
        private readonly ScoreRepository obj = new ScoreRepository();

        public ActionResult Index(string scheduleId)
        {
            var model = obj.GetStudentlistOfSchedule(scheduleId);
            return View(model);

        }
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View("Create");

            // return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Lesson lesson)
        {
            obj.AddNewLesson(lesson);
            obj.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Lesson");
        }
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            return View(obj.FindLessonById(id));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Lesson lesson)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                obj.Update(lesson);
                obj.Save();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Lesson");
        }
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            obj.RemoveLesson(obj.FindLessonById(id));
            obj.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Lesson");

            // return View();
        }

    }
}
```

What should i do ?

Best regards

Comment: Did you build the project after you added the class?

Comment: Thank you .I didn't build it .